# Simulink: apply constant velocity to model

Tags: matlab, simulink

i want to model a spring-damper-mass system and apply a constant velocity on it during the whole simulation. how can it be done? i tried by adding a constant, but it only will be added to the system at the beginning. also a step block couldn't solve my problem either.

i would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 6):

If you drew your Simulink diagram using two integrators to compute acceleration->velocity and velocity->position, then you would need to replace the first integrator (acceleration->velocity) with a constant block to provide the fixed velocity input to the system. As a result, the resisting force will be larger and larger in the direction opposite of the motion.

[image]